# Java - Cannot modify Embedded Database table using variable

Tags: java, database, javadb

I'm using Java Netbean with Embedded JavaDB at directory D:. First, when I build this project i can CRUD without problem, but after moving to embedded Database, now i cant use delete or update SQL(using local String variable),

With this SQL it always show :"java Exception: A lock could not be obtained within the time"

```
"delete from table where id='"+txtID.getText()+"'"
```

I can only use this

```
"delete from table where id='0001'"
```

Both of these codes have same output. Tried to put `.toString()` but still won't work

Comment: Are you closing your `Statement`'s, `ResultSets` and `Connection`s when you're finished when them?  Are you creating multiple `Connection`s simultaneously? Do you have write permissions of the database directory?

Comment: yes I did close them..